# Live Detect iframe page onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I have a div element that contains some iframes. At times, I destroy those iframes and create new one, but I always need to know when each of them (also those added later) has finished loading. I thought that the following code would work but I get nothing logged to the debug console. Any help?

```
  // doesn't work
  $('#viewport').on('load', 'iframe', function() {
    console.log('LOADED!');
    return true;
  });

  // doesn't work either
  $('#viewport').on('ready', 'iframe', function() {
    console.log('LOADED!');
    return true;
  });
```

Comment: `load` is only for images, isn't it?

Comment: nope http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ it also works for windows, frames, iframes and the like

Comment: Try with: `$('#viewport').on('load' , function() {
    console.log('LOADED!');
    return true;
  });`

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the frame finishes loading before you add the event.

Try to add the event before you add it to the DOM.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
// set iframe properties
$(iframe ).on('ready', 'iframe', function() {
  console.log('LOADED!');
});
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty convinced that this can't be done with dynamic iframes. From the jQuery site (under the deprecated `load()` function:

> Note: The .live() and .delegate() methods cannot be used to detect the load event of an iframe. The load event does not correctly bubble up the parent document and the event.target isn't set by Firefox, IE9 or Chrome, which is required to do event delegation.

I can't get a similar project to work, either.